# Jackson - Generics- T as reified parameter

Tags: kotlin, generics, jackson, objectmapper

I'm trying to implement an abstract message-consumer with kotlin and jackson for RabbitMQ. The setup for the consumers works fine, so I omit that in the code-snippets.
The Problem is only in regard to parsing the String-payload to a generic-type object.

My Goal is to have an abstract class like :

```
abstract class AbstractRetryConsumer<T>(val queueName:String) : MessageListener {
// Autowiring and seting up the Beans
...
    override fun onMessage(msg: Message) {
       val msgPayload = String(msg.body, Charsets.UTF_8)
  // the following line doesn't compile
       val readValue = objectMapper.readValue<T>(msgPayload)
       processEvent(readValue)
    }

    abstract fun processEvent(payload: T)
...
}
```

Then I'd be able to implement a Consumer like:

```
@Service
class NotificationConsumer(
) : AbstractRetryConsumer<Notification>("myQueue") {

// gets the payload as a parsed object
    override fun processEvent(payload: Notification) {
        println("payload ist: $payload")
    }
}
```

The compiler won't accept that. The error is:
**Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.**

I know there are many similar questions, but I didn't find an answer to my problem.

Thanks for your inquires and answers

Comment: I don't see where you have added the reified parameter. Did you add it on the class level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Jackson Kotlin module, the object mapper has an inline extension `readValue` with reified generic parameter. Since the paramter in your call `objectMapper.readValue<T>(msgPayload)` is reified, your class `AbstractRetryConsumer<T>` also needs to define a reified parameter `T`. However, that means your class has to be inline, and it looks too big to be inline. Therefore, you should add a JavaClass argument to your constructor and call the non-extension version of `readValue`:

```
val readValue = objectMapper.readValue(msgPayload, payloadClass)
```